# preg_match this or this but not match any of this

Tags: php, regex, expression, preg-match

so, I look around a while but I'm having problems.

I need a preg_match function with a regular expression that found words in a string, just to match the whole pattern, no replace or found position.

`"mct" or "MT" /i` (no case sensitive)

but at the same time, this string must not have any word starting or containing  "md", "med", "burn", "mull", "des a", "hot tem" /i (also no case sensitive)

no case sensitive at all...

so I tried someting like this:

```
/(mt|mct)(?!med)(?!md)(?!burn)(?!mull)(?!des a)(?!hot tem)))*$/i
```

but it seems not working the way I expected.

Example of expected behavior:

```
 $string                     |STATUS

McTNug10GdPap               | TRUE 
McTQQMdDobPap               | FALSE (has "Md")
McT Pollo Esp Dobl Gd P     | TRUE
MTD McPollo Spicy Med       | FALSE (has "Med")
MegaBig Chikn Nugg          | FALSE
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of a string?

Comment: In the question it says must contain `mct` or `MT`, but the regex has `(mc|mct)`, which is it so I can update my answer accordingly?

Comment: I was just checking you answer, yes, it must have ("MT" or "mct" no case sensitive) one or another, but I don't know if "(mt|mct)" is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex based off the requirements.

```
/^(?!.*(?:me?d|burn|mull|des a|hot tem)).*mc?t.*$/i
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/tV1dC7/4)

Comment: This seeks match  for "mct" but not "mt" ?

Comment: Totally working! :) this is just what I was looking for, thank you hwn. Just another question if I wanted to add another two matching words to  "mt" and "mct" like; "duo" or "fresh" (4 words to match) can I add it with just a pipe? | ?, Thanks

Comment: Yes you can.. `(mc?t|duo|fresh)`

Answer (score 0):

Change your match to two patterns

```
if(preg_match("/(mc|mct)/",$string) &&
!preg_match("/(md|burn|mull|des a|hot tem)/",$string))
```